# Bake imported image to vertex colors

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor, vertex-colors

I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find an answer to this issue.

All I want to do is generate a UV Map, upload an image onto that UV Map, and then export a .ply file with the vertex colors baked in from the uploaded image.

I'm using 2.76; Blender seems to really want to go the other way. When I 'bake to vertex colors' it doesn't seem to have an option to pull the colors from the UV map.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Blender can't take vertex colors from UV map. UV map doesn't store them, it's just coordinates of the vertices but not an image. Generally it looks like Blender doesn't find source for the baking so try either connecting vertex colors to e.g. Emission shader and baking Emit pass or using addon like in the linked question

Comment: Thank you both. The addon in the linked question was exactly what I needed!